# Problem with BeginInvoke-EndInvoke

Tags: .net, windows, crash, event-log

guys!
I have problem with my .net application. When I try to print in my program then it close with crash 
with any error messages. Information about error I've got from event viewer in Windows. Can someone help me? But on another computer it works fine. My guess is that something with security policy. Besides, program crash but print still work fine.
Below is info:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   5000
Date:       2/25/2011
Time:       8:56:47 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   PROTO
Description:
EventType clr20r3, P1 invoice browser.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4d67b263, P4 system.windows.forms, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4333aefa, P7 1508, P8 17, P9 system.invalidoperationexception, P10 NIL.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 63 00 6c 00 72 00 32 00   c.l.r.2.
0008: 30 00 72 00 33 00 2c 00   0.r.3.,.
0010: 20 00 69 00 6e 00 76 00    .i.n.v.
0018: 6f 00 69 00 63 00 65 00   o.i.c.e.
0020: 20 00 62 00 72 00 6f 00    .b.r.o.
0028: 77 00 73 00 65 00 72 00   w.s.e.r.
0030: 2e 00 65 00 78 00 65 00   ..e.x.e.
0038: 2c 00 20 00 31 00 2e 00   ,. .1...
0040: 30 00 2e 00 30 00 2e 00   0...0...
0048: 30 00 2c 00 20 00 34 00   0.,. .4.
0050: 64 00 36 00 37 00 62 00   d.6.7.b.
0058: 32 00 36 00 33 00 2c 00   2.6.3.,.
0060: 20 00 73 00 79 00 73 00    .s.y.s.
0068: 74 00 65 00 6d 00 2e 00   t.e.m...
0070: 77 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00   w.i.n.d.
0078: 6f 00 77 00 73 00 2e 00   o.w.s...
0080: 66 00 6f 00 72 00 6d 00   f.o.r.m.
0088: 73 00 2c 00 20 00 32 00   s.,. .2.
0090: 2e 00 30 00 2e 00 30 00   ..0...0.
0098: 2e 00 30 00 2c 00 20 00   ..0.,. .
00a0: 34 00 33 00 33 00 33 00   4.3.3.3.
00a8: 61 00 65 00 66 00 61 00   a.e.f.a.
00b0: 2c 00 20 00 31 00 35 00   ,. .1.5.
00b8: 30 00 38 00 2c 00 20 00   0.8.,. .
00c0: 31 00 37 00 2c 00 20 00   1.7.,. .
00c8: 73 00 79 00 73 00 74 00   s.y.s.t.
00d0: 65 00 6d 00 2e 00 69 00   e.m...i.
00d8: 6e 00 76 00 61 00 6c 00   n.v.a.l.
00e0: 69 00 64 00 6f 00 70 00   i.d.o.p.
00e8: 65 00 72 00 61 00 74 00   e.r.a.t.
00f0: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 65 00   i.o.n.e.
00f8: 78 00 63 00 65 00 70 00   x.c.e.p.
0100: 74 00 69 00 6f 00 6e 00   t.i.o.n.
0108: 20 00 4e 00 49 00 4c 00    .N.I.L.
0110: 0d 00 0a 00               ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all! I have fixed my problem!
Believe you or not but problem was in Microsoft.ReportViwer. 
I have installed ReportViwer SP1 and fixed problem.

To determinate this problem I spent about 8 hours. For me helpfull was AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. So if your application crashed without any messegging try to
subscribe on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. Also I was using log4net. The cool logger.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting exception handling around the block where you print; a System.InvalidOperationException is being thrown, and if you catch it, you should be able to get more information (InnerException, etc.).